# Is it possible to move All Resources to documents folder

Tags: ios, image, file, ios5

I want to change my images dynamically.  At every app launch i am requesting to the server for updates. It is sending the new images if it has. I am storing the images inside documents directory. When i add the existing image into the document directory the old image got replaced.

I had embedded few images with the app (it is under resources). I can't replace the images from resource due to apples signing policy. 
My current implementation

```
if(image is present in documents)
       use this
else
     take it from resources
```

In case the user wants to change all the images, Resources will contain all the  images and documents will contain all the images. So it is leading to duplication

So i want to move  from Standard resources to Documents directory 
 Can i use  "Container Migration Manifest"?

Comment: it is a good occasion for you to meet and date the `NSFileManager` **[class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**, but I have a bad news: you have only read permission for the _resource_ folder, therefore you cannot modify, remove or add to and from the _resources_ programatically.

Comment: Can keep my image files  somewhere  else in the project and later move into documents?

Comment: you can store them in the _resources_ folder only... and from there you could copy them into the _Document_ folder later, if it is needed.